# java constructed relative path using "../../" is not recognized, why?

Tags: java, string, file, directory, relative-path

I'm using intellij for java developing, under my project/src directory, I got a "my.json" file, and my java program is:

```
import java.io.File;
public class My {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String s = My.class.getResource(".") + "../../src/my.json";
        File f = new File(s);
        System.out.println(s+" exists: "+f.exists());
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
file:/Users/x/java_local/target/classes/../../src/my.json exists: false
```

But if I "ls" under command line:

```
ls /Users/x/java_local/target/classes/../../src/my.json
```

Then I can see it.

So it seems that the java code constructed relative path is not valid. If I use absolute path in code, then it works.

I'm on mac. Any explanations on how this problem happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison you present in the question explains the nature of the problem clearly.  Consider this code:

> ```
>         File f = new File(s);
>         System.out.println(s+" exists: "+f.exists());
> ```

and the corresponding output:

> ```
> file:/Users/x/java_local/target/classes/../../src/my.json exists: false
> ```

Evidently `s`, the string you are attempting to use as a file name, is `file:/Users/x/java_local/target/classes/../../src/my.json`.  See that "file:" at the beginning?  You have a valid String representation of a URL, but `File(String)` expects the argument to be a plain path.

Possibly you want

```
    File f = new File(new URI(s));
```

, but note that this will fail if your class is packaged inside a Jar, because then your URI will have the `jar:` scheme, and `File(URI)` accepts only URIs having the `file:` scheme.

If you want to read a resource associated with your class and located relative to it, then I would suggest using `Class.getResourceAsStream(relativePath)` and consuming the resulting `InputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `My.class.getResource(".")` with `My.class.getResource(".").getPath()`.

`file:/Users/x/java_local/target/classes/../../src/my.json` is literally checked as a file path with `file:` prefix and thus is not found in the system.